# Excel - Restrict Options in Drop Down Fields to those currently not in use

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

I restrict the options (an ID) for column A:A to those given in a drop down menu.

The possible elements are in K1:K10. In L1:L10 there is a flag (0/1) whether the ID is currently already in use or not.

Now I want to restrict the options in the drop down menu to those from K1:K10 which are flagged as 0 in L1:L10. Those flags can change multiple over the life sycle of that document. While in use, I don't want that ID to be selectable. Ones no longer flagged as in use, I want it to become available again.

Comment: So make a list in column M of those available. Even multiplying by 0 can work.

Comment: That is a good option, indeed. Is there a way to not include 0 in the drop down option (currently, I use "" instead of 0 but ideally, that should also not be an option in the menu).

Comment: Doesn't the drop down dialogue box have an option to not include blanks?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for me, though. Maybe because Excel interprets "" as empty string and not as blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Excel version this may be a solution, as Validation Lists can refer to dynamic arrays.

Use the FILTER function to create a dynamic array of valid names in cell M1.

```
=FILTER(K1:K10,NOT(L1:L10))
```

Then set the Validation List to `=$M1$#`. NB the `#` is important as it tells Excel you are using a dynamic range rather than a standard cell reference.

[image]

and now (if you have Calculation set to Automatic) you should see the list of available names change as you change 1's and 0's in Column L.

[image]

Comment: For me - don't ask me why - the second part of the formular was not NOT(L1:L10) but L1:L10. But then it works perfectly.

Comment: @user9092346 Whatever works! From your question, I read it that you only wanted to include names where the flag in column L was zero.